# Store custom object in JLabel on event

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing a drag and drop of custom objects into JLabels and am able to reference the object during the transfer process (change label String to received object toString), but unsure of how to actually store the custom object in the JLabel or build a reference.

What is the best way to accomplish this during the transfer process?

Here is the working transfer code that receives the object and uses it to set text (much thanks to a previous answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855184/drag-and-drop-custom-object-from-jlist-into-jlabel/13856193#13856193):

```
public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
            boolean accept = false;
            if (canImport(support)) {
                try {
                    Transferable t = support.getTransferable();
                    Object value = t.getTransferData(PersonTransferable.PERSON_FLAVOR);
                    if (value instanceof Person) {
                        Component component = support.getComponent();
                        if (component instanceof JLabel) {
                            ((JLabel)component).setText(((Person)value).toString());
                            //action here

                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return accept;
        }
```

The JLabels have specific instance variables that I'd like to store them to. Since I have the component (JLabel) and value (custom object), can I make this link?

Worst case scenario, I just have to build a TransferHandler for *each* label and reference the value exactly. Is this maybe best practice anyways?

Comment: Why would you store an object in a JLabel? You could use a `Map<JLabel, Person>` such as with a HashMap if you wish to associate a Person with a JLabel, but I guess you'd probably rather put the Person into an ArrayList or other collection.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mapping, so that might be the trick.

Comment: As a (very sloppy) workaround in the meantime, I'm using the JLabel tooltip as the reference with an if statement matching the tooltip with the associated value... I definitely need to study up on mapping.

Comment: What information are you storing, and why must it be associated with the JLabel? You would only use the Map if you must associated the object with the JLabel, but again that may not even be necessary. A JLabel is used for display of information not for storage. You need to clarify the problem you're trying to solve, not how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: You can use the `JComponent` methods `putClientProperty()` and `gettClientProperty()` as needed. Also cite this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13856193/230513) to your previous question on this topic.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it is to reference an object with the JLabel.

Comment: @trashgod would this support objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of choices that I can see

**Choice #1**

Create a `Map` of some kind and store the object against the label, using the label as it's key

```
Map<JLabel, Person> mapPeople = new HashMap<JLable, Person>(25)
```

Then in your import method

```
mapPeople.put((JLabel)component, (Person)value);
```

**Choice #2**

Take advantage of the `put/getClientProperty` to store the value against a named key...

In your import method...

```
((JLabel)component).putClientProperty("person", value);
```

And when you need it again

Person person = (Person)label.getClientProperty("person");

**Choice #3**

Create a custom label that is capable of referencing the person directly.

```
public class PersonLabel extends JLabel {
    private Person person;
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
        setText(person == null ? null : person.toString());
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
}
```

Basically, you would use this component in place of the normal `JLabel`, make sure you cast it correctly.

Credit to Hovercraft and trashgod for mentioning most of this first.

**Final Choice**

The final choice will come down to your own design, requirements and how re-usable you want the solution to be.

If this is a "one" off requirement for your application, then the `Map` and client properties are reasonable solutions.

The `Map` is more highly visible to other developers, it obvious what you are trying to do.  It is, however, easy to mess up.  Having the map either contain irrelevant data or have missing data because some one forgot to/or didn't know to follow the requirements.

The `clientProperty` does solve some the short comings of the `Map` in this sense, as you a re dealing with a single component, not a component and a `Map` (although it's still possible for developers to forget to set the property) but has a much lower visibility when compared to the `Map`.  It might take longer for developers to realise how you are storing/retrieving the data.

It does, how ever, have the advantage of been simple.  You can pass a reference to the label and you have not just the label, but also the `Person` as well.

The custom label provides you the opportunity for flexibility.  It's more obvious then the `clientProperty` solution, as it has defined public methods.  It also allows you the opportunity to setup the `TransferHandler` when the label is created, rather then having to establish each one individually each time you want to re-use the solution.

What it's going to come down to is this.  Do you want a quick, once of solution, or do you want something to is self-contained and re-usable.  The `Map` and `clientProperty` choices are relatively quick to implement and use.  The custom component will take a little more effort but will generally result in a more re-usable solution.  It's all up to you ;)

Comment: All very good answers, thank you. I think the last one will probably suit my needs the best since I'll be setting the custom object with a DnD.